# Kettle - Two csv inputs into PostgreSQL output

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a class project using Pentaho. I need to create a dashboard using 2 different inputs into a PostgreSQL output. My problem is, using Kettle, I have to match two different .csv files that go into the Postgres. One of the csv is about crimes, the other is about weather. I manually added two columns into the weather one, so they have two matching columns: 'Month' and 'Year'.

[image: kettle transformation]

My question is how can I use this matching columns (or does doing that make any sense) so I can later create the dashboard and make queries like 'What crimes where committed when it was raining?'.

Sorry if I'm not very accurate, I'm a bit lost at using Pentaho. If anyone could give me some help I would be thankful.

Comment: Do you want the output to be in a single table or two separate tables?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I need to be able to do queries based on the two csv. So I don't know whats the best option. I need to select the measures/dimensions too. My idea was do some filters like sort by 'city where it happened', 'murder weapon', 'weather'. I'm really having trouble trying to understand these concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is to join two CSV files, please check the Join step.